# Not getting the required output while converting pandas series to string

Tags: python, pandas

While using the below code, I am getting only a single output for the entire column. But I want the output for each row. I wanted to know how can I do it? Here a is my string which I converted from a dataframe.

```
from textblob.classifiers import DecisionTreeClassifier

train = [('I love this sandwich.', 'pos'),
        ('This is an amazing place!', 'pos'),
        ('I feel very good about these beers.', 'pos'),
        ('I do not like this restaurant', 'neg'),
        ('I am tired of this stuff.', 'neg'),
        ("I can't deal with this", 'neg'),
        ("My boss is horrible.", "neg")
    ]
ho=tweets['twt'] % where tweets['twt'] contains tweets in text format
a=ho.to_string(buf=None, columns=None, col_space=None, header=True, index=True, na_rep='NaN', formatters=None, float_format=None, sparsify=False, index_names=True, justify=None, line_width=None, max_rows=None, max_cols=None, show_dimensions=False)

cl = DecisionTreeClassifier(train)        
blob = TextBlob(a, classifier=cl)
for s in blob.sentences:
    print(s)
    print(s.classify())
```

Current output:-
[image]

Comment: what is the output of `print(blob.sentences)`

Comment: Remember *always*  `ctrl`+`c` and `ctrl`+`v` is wayyy better than posting a image.

Comment: 0   1496805199.864178::rt arundhati ...
1   1496805283.4774578::rt  pathetic excus...
2   1496805507.171569:: pathetic excuse...
3   1496805550.932861::: pathetic excuse...
4   1496805557.0368845::dare to touch sbi on rbi d...
5   1496805557.0418837::dare to touch sbi on rbi d...
6   1496805569.787344::dare to touch sbi on rbi da...
7   1496805600.8357852::sbin - dare to touch sbi o...


neg

Comment: What is `ho`? The variable is not defined..

Comment: Exactly what is `ho` ? `NameError: name 'ho' is not defined` is coming

Comment: @cardamom Series

Comment: It contains the extracted tweets from the twitter.

Comment: Okay but where have you mentioned it in your code. What value does it contain... update your code along with it